# MarkLogic Assessment test retake

Tags: marklogic

friends

Please guide me with MarkLogic Assessment test retake, is it possible to retake the MarkLogic Assessment test. Please let me know

Thanks in advance 
Rajesh

Comment: checking -- are you referring to the [MLU assessments](https://mlu.marklogic.com/assessments/) or the certification test?

Answer (score 3):

Odd forum to ask the question. I believe you're allowed to take the assessment tests as many times as you like. I know that I've completed them in the past and they appear in the account history, but the UI allows me to start the assessment over again. I suppose that in the worst-case, you could use a different email account to register and complete the tests again using that account.